# Many-to-many one way mapping and use only two tables

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two entities: Project, Employee

- Employee has primary key {employeeId} + some other attributes
- Project has primary key {projectId}

Code:

```
public class Employee {
  Long employeeId;
  String name;     
}
public class Project {
  Long projectId;
  Collection<Employee> employees;
}
```

Employee and Project is a one way many-to-many relationship.  The general approach is to have three tables: Employee, Project, EmployeesAssignedToProjects.

```
Employee
----------
employeeId (PK)
name

Project
----------
projectId (PK)

EmployeesAssignedToProjects
----------------------------
projectId (FK)
employeeId (FK)
{projectId,employeeId} (PK)
```

Since Project doesn't have other attributes other than its id, the Project table is not really necessary.  This brings to the question of how should this many-to-many relationship be mapped now that Project essentially maps to EmployeesAssignedToProjects.

Note that Employee doesn't have a pointer back to Project.  The typical mappedBy construct can't be used here.

[-- Update --]

The problem is a little more complicated: Both Project and Employee have composite keys.

- Project's key is {companyId,projectId}
- Employee's key is {companyId,employeeId}

I adopted the 3 tables set up.  Table PROJECT_EMPLOYEE has 3 columns: companyId, employeeId, projectId.  And I mapped in xml:

```
<many-to-many name="PROJECT" >
 <join-table name="PROJECT_EMPLOYEE">
  <join-column name="companyId" referenced-column-name="companyId"/>
  <join-column name="employeeId" referenced-column-name="employeeId" />
  <inverse-join-column name="companyId" referenced-column-name="companyId" />
  <inverse-join-column name="projectId" referenced-column-name="projectId" />
 </join-table>
</many-to-many>
```

I received a error complaining companyId appearing multiple times:
Repeated column in mapping for collection: Project.employees column: companyId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that Employee doesn't have a pointer back to Project. The typical mappedBy construct can't be used here.

This is irrelevant anyway.

And the fact is that all `ManyToMany` relationships require a `JoinTable`. The `JoinTable` is defined using the `@JoinTable` either implicitly or explicitly.

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PROJECTID")
    private Long projectId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="PROJECT_EMPLOYEE",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_PROJECTID", referencedColumnName="PROJECTID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEEID", referencedColumnName="EMPLOYEEID")})
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
    ...
}
```

You can *try* to define the `PROJECT` table itself as the `JoinTable` if you only need **reads** support (and I'm not even sure it will work correctly) but this won't work for **writes**.

In other words, I would stick to the regular construct to represent many-to-many relations in a database, i.e. with a join table.

Comment: @Candy You're welcome. But please, post the *new* question as a new question. Link it to this one if you want but your update is a different question and problem, even if related. Please just don't mix problems in a single question. I won't answer here.

Comment: Is it possible to map @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEEID" .. to another unique key on the employe table? I am unable to do that. I'd like a string unique constraint to show up instead of integers

Answer (score 0):

Given the class files you provided you probably are trying to change `n - m` relationship to `n - 0..1` relationship.

This can be done by removing the `EmployeesAssignedToProjects` and denormalizing the `Employee` table by adding `projectId (FK)` to it:

```
Employee
----------
employeeId (PK)
projectId (FK)
name

Project
----------
projectId (PK)
```

Is this what you really want? I dont recommend it.

Comment: I don't want to denormalize the Employee table.  Thanks.